# continous check & conditional rename of linux subfolders

Tags: regex, linux, bash, rename, file-rename

**Issue:** I'm currently looking for a way to automate a renaming process in a continously changing subfolder tree in debian.

**Goal:**  For kodi scrapers to recognise anime tv shows with a modified naming pattern without any additional manual input from my end with each new downloaded episode.

Here are some common formats of a file naming conventions in that scene and all three won't be recognised for different reasons.

1. [NoobSubs] Japanese anime name **06** (1080p Blu-ray Dual Audio 8bit AAC)[4564568].mkv

Two free standing double digits won't be recognised as an episode number. An 'e' prefix is mandatory

2. [Anime Time] Japanese anime name  - **S04E06** [1080p][HEVC 10bit x265][AAC][Eng Sub] (English anime name).mkv

The scraper uses anidb as it's database, which treats every season as an individual show- so it must be scraped as season one (S01) or not at all, which defaults to season one. As soon as it says 'S02+', it won't be able to find it

3. [SubsPlease] Japanese anime name  **S2 - 11** (1080p) [4864654].mkv

Both of the upper two issues combined- Its must be S01 or nothing and E11 instead of 11.

I've played around a bit with regex and with the help of someone on stackoverflow

```
Prepend 'E' to free standing double digits
\b([0-9]{2})\b
Substitution: E$1
```

Delete antything with S01-S99

```
\b[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])\b
```

I assume the way to go here is either a *cronjob* commandline or *watch* with a script which is executed every 10 minutes or so.
Unfortunately I don't have the slightest idea how to build that.

**[EDIT]**
ok I found several bits I could use and patched it together like Frankensteins Monster, but in it's current state it won't come to life.
Can anyone help me out to make this work?

```
while true; do
#recursive directory watches
inotifywait -e modify,create,delete -r //srv/dev-disk-123/MEDIA2/anime/ && \

#modify any filename in filetree which applies
start_dir="//srv/dev-disk-123/MEDIA2/anime/"
find "$start_dir" -name '*.*' -type f \
  |sort \
  |while read name; do 
     ((i++))
     mv -i "$name" \
#remove season part
       "$(printf 's/[sS](0[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])/' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename "$name")")"
#prepend E to free standing double digits
       "$(printf 's/\b([0-9]{2})\b/' "$(dirname "$name")" $((i)) "$(basename "$name")")"
#not sure how to add the E$1 here

   done

done
```

Comment: You could perhaps run a service that does `inotifywait` to get an immediate notification when something changes instead.

Comment: oooh that sounds like a much better approach than continously checking! Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. It can be a bit tricky to handle the `inotify` events but yes, it's nice to be able to subscribe to changes.